# issue with the conditional operator

Tags: c, gcc, ternary-operator

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", 4 ?: 8);
}
```

According to the C standard this program is invalid because it is missing an expression between the `?` and `:`.But The interesting thing is that there is when I compile the code it is printing `4`.how come it will print `4` rather than showing any compile error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a `gcc` extension.

```
x ? : y
```

is equivalent to

```
x ? x : y
```

See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) for detail.

Comment: +1 also for linking the gcc docs.